# local disable of auto align in visual studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, pretty-print

Is there a way to **disable** auto alignment only per specific code part, like here:

```
            public Enum options{
            NONE =                            0,
            OptionaA =                0b1000000,
            OptionaB =               0b10000000,
            OptionaC =               0b100000000,
            OptionaD_LONGName =     0b1000000000,
            OptionaE_short =       0b10000000000
            }
```

I would like to add some # before and after that code to prevent Visual studio from auto aligning that...
Is there any way to do that?
Thanks

Comment: No, there's no `#pragma` for this. You can customize the formatting options in the Options dialog. The settings you see are the ones you get. Pad the values out with 0s if you want to make them look nicer.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Saved me lots of search... At least I know there's no option..